# Website page is suddenly broken after trying to use an inbuilt tool

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a project for my client. I was editing the page with WordPress Gutenberg editor and when I clicked `Edit in WordPress` the website home page was broken and I could no longer fix it.
I tried these approaches:

1. Tried reinstalling the theme
2. Checked the code for error but could not find anything.
3. Looked into the browser console for errors and found these files are missing `bootstrap.min.js.map` `popper.min.js.map` `style.css.map` `bootstrap.min.css.map`
4. I checked other pages on the website but they are working fine even if some of these files are missing.
5. Installed this theme on my localhost and then tried to copy all the theme data into this one but it messed up the code even more.

Now I am not sure why do I have this issue suddenly on my website but I can't seem to find a solution for this.
Please check out the links below:

1. (the broken page) https://cmedia.host
2. (Page that is working just fine on the website) https://cmedia.host/nom-de-domaine/

Can you please check and help me fix the issue here?

Comment: Look in your browser's console, it can't find the gutenerg.css or 2 icons.

Comment: I can see only 4 warnings. That these 4 files I mentioned are missing.

Comment: Do you have a recent backup

Comment: Editing wordpress page or posts with a different editor (i.e. using theme editor and then Gutenberg or vice-versa) is known to generate this type of issues. can you try to edit it again with the original editor (Gutenberg) ?

Comment: @avia it worked. As soon as I used the editor, it fixed the code automatically. Thank you

Comment: @ArpitJangir Glad I could help, it's a very frustrating and weird issue...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to redo the same steps. It looks like Gutenberg was missing and when I tried editing the page using Gutenberg, it broke the code.

Then followed the same steps and tried to redo the steps using another editor and it was fixed in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Editing wordpress page or posts with a different editor (i.e. using theme editor and then Gutenberg or vice-versa) is known to generate this type of issues. Try to edit it again with the original editor (Gutenberg) that should fix it.